# Carry-out bit detection in Verilog

Tags: verilog

Just started to learn about Verilog. Anyway, I can't figure out why my code doesn't output the overflow into the carry bit `cout`. So, the addition of 8'h~42 + 8'h45 + 1'b1 = 9'h103. However, I can't seem to get the overflow in the `cout` (Shown in the code below). The 9th bit is truncated. All I had gotten was 003 (The carry-out bit is still 0), instead of 103. Not sure where I'm going wrong with this. Hope someone can help!

Note - `Matrix_A` and `Matrix_B` hex values are gotten from a COE file, which is 42 and 45 respectively.

```
wire [0:0] cout;
wire    [7:0] matrix_A;
wire    [7:0] matrix_B;
wire [7:0] matrix_BA;

assign {cout,matrix_BA} = (~matrix_A + matrix_B + 1'b1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested at Edaplayground. I can't see anything wrong with it......

EDIT: actually, my example was a bit different than yours. Rewritting the design and the testbench gives me a hint: when you add the three components in the `assign`, all of them are "promoted" to 9 bits, but as you are negating `matrix_A`, the promoted bit is negated as well.

```
~42h + 45h + 1 = ~01000010 + 01000101 + 1 = (promoted to 9 bits) =
~001000010 + 001000101 + 000000001 = (applying negation) = 
110111101 + 001000101 + 000000001 = 1000000011 (a 10 bit result, which is
truncated to 9 bits) = 000000011 , making your carry to be 0.
```

Try this:

```
assign {cout,matrix_BA} = {1'b0, ~matrix_A} + {1'b0, matrix_B} + 9'b1;
```

You can test it by yourself here: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/iGQP